# How to fix a window, keeping rain out but allowing wind in?

Tags: windows

It's always raining heavily here at my place and I had to keep the room windows shut due to the electrical appliances near the window inside the room. However, the room quickly becomes ill-ventilated.

What's the best solution to this dilemna?

Is there a *window* or material covering that does not allow rain and water to enter, yet allows the wind to enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answer JonW gave, but also would suggest just putting an awning over your existing window and opening it from the top as it's likely to be a bit less expensive.

Edit:
I passed this house fixed type awning system and decided to grab a shot to add t this post

[image]

Comment: However, awning's don't really keep heavy rain out unless they are  *really* long outwards right?

Comment: With a top opening window and a reasonable sized awning, the rain would have to practically go upwards to get into the room. (which could probably happen with a lot of wind, but in practice it works well -- my parents old house had awnings and they could keep the top half of the windows open even during heavy rains).

Comment: I believe there are also retractable (roll-up) awnings that be set as be has high or low profile as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a [Tilt and Turn window](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=tilt+and+turn+window&btnG=&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1) - a window that tilts inwards slightly (and locks in place so that it doesn't tip back anymore) to let air circulate, but can also be opened as a traditional window too (albeit one that typically opens inwards instead of outwards).

[image]

Comment: I've also seen ones that open out/with the opening at the bottom rather than in/with the opening at the top.

Comment: @MarkBooth: I'd still opt for the top-opening ones. Don't want any curious little creatures nipping in for a visit!

Comment: That depends on how practical it is to get to your sills. If a creature can get to *my* flats sills then they could certainly climb up to the top gap too. *8') What I have also noticed though is that with top gaps, wind blown rain can get further into the room than with gaps at the bottom.

Comment: @JonW, I don't see how this could actually keep the rain out. The rain would get into the room though the hole wouldn't it?

Comment: Is this any better than the standard [double-hung window](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+hung+window&source=lnms&tbm=isch) that can slide open from the top? Maybe with the addition of a [window canopy](https://www.google.com/search?q=window+canopy+rain+window&source=lnms&tbm=isch) or [awning](https://www.google.com/search?q=window+awning&source=lnms&tbm=isch) at the top?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the loss of light from the window, a louver could be installed.

Comment: Does a louver gives a stuffy room?

Comment: @Pacerier, a louver would definitely help a stuffy room.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my home. I live in sausalito,ca. by san francisco bay with a southern exposure. In winter we get 40 plus winds and pouring rain. The rain paired with the wind has even blown in through the top of the window casement.

Two years ago I found what I call window baffles, by accident, through the vermont country store co. they are wonderful! We have just endured 16 days of torrential rain and over 50 mile an hour winds. The top of the window casement leaked, but not my window baffles.

I couldn't find them at the vermont country store. But, I did see them online. Go to google and type; window screens that keep out the rain. The first thing you will see on the top right are; different drawings of screens. the one named [thermwell products aws1207](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00133H7K4) adjustable screen window with ventilator looks like mine.

It's a regular screen on the backside and the louvred baffles face inside. I have found that it works well with the baffles facing up. Then just slam your window down hard on the baffle. this makes a good seal. good luck, you're going to love these.